# Scripting Azure Time Series Insights Data Access Policies

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-sdk, azure-rest-api, azure-timeseries-insights

There exists a manual way to add users to the `Time Series Insights` using `Data Access Policies`.

Withstanding that, there is no way available to add users in bulk.

[image]

Can both the scenarios be scripted/automated using `PowerShell/Azure REST API/SDK`?

Comment: Hi, may I know if your problem was solved ? If the solution I provided below works, could you please mark my answer as "accepted", thanks.

Answer (score 0):

According to my research, we can use the following Azure Rest API to create data access policy in Time Series Insights policy. For more details, please refer to the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/time-series-insights/management/accesspolicies/createorupdate)

```
PUT https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.TimeSeriesInsights/environments/{environmentName}/accessPolicies/{accessPolicyName}?api-version=2018-08-15-preview
```

For example

```
Connect-AzAccount



$tenantId="<your tenant id>"
$resource="https://management.core.windows.net/"



$context=Get-AzContext 



$token=$context.TokenCache.ReadItems() |Where-Object { ($_.TenantId -eq $tenantId) -and ($_.Resource -eq $resource)  }
$accesstoken=$token.AccessToken
$body =@{
 "properties" = @{

  "principalObjectId" ="<the object id of the user or service principal>"
  "roles"= @("Reader")
  "description"="reader" 
 }



}| ConvertTo-Json



$url="https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.TimeSeriesInsights/environments/{environmentName}/accessPolicies/{accessPolicyName}?api-version=2018-08-15-preview"
$result =Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $url  -Method Put -Headers @{"Authorization" = "Bearer $accesstoken"} -Body $body -UseBasicParsing



$result.properties
```

[image]